# remove several classes of controller in an array using va_list

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I want to remove any `UIViewController class` that appears in the `va_list` in my `navigationController.viewControllers`

Take a brief look at my code:

```
- (NSArray *)removeInControllerArray:(NSArray *)controllers
                     unwantedClasses:(__unsafe_unretained Class *)unwantedClass, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list controllerList;
    va_start(controllerList, unwantedClass);
    NSMutableArray *mutableControllers = [controllers mutableCopy];
    __unsafe_unretained Class *tempClass = unwantedClass;

    while (tempClass) {
        for (UIViewController *tempController in mutableControllers) {
            if ([tempController isKindOfClass:tempClass]) {
                [mutableControllers removeObject:tempController];
                continue;
            }
        }
        tempClass = va_arg(controllerList, Class *);
    }

    va_end(controllerList);
    return [mutableControllers copy];
}
```

First thing, it shows error in this line of code `[tempController isKindOfClass:tempClass]`, saying:

> Error: Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C
>   pointer to 'Class' is disallowed with ARC
>
> Warning: Incompatible pointer types sending '__unsafe_unretained Class
>   *' to parameter of type 'Class'

- So, how do I get rid of this error ? I'm not familliar with the concept of pointer :(
- Did I use `__unsafe_unretained` correctly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the class directly, not a pointer to one. Just get rid of all of the asterisks after `Class`.

Here it is:

```
- (NSArray *)removeInControllerArray:(NSArray *)controllers
                     unwantedClasses:(__unsafe_unretained Class)unwantedClass, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list controllerList;
    va_start(controllerList, unwantedClass);
    NSMutableArray *mutableControllers = [controllers mutableCopy];
    __unsafe_unretained Class tempClass = unwantedClass;

    while (tempClass) {
        for (UIViewController *tempController in mutableControllers) {
            if ([tempController isKindOfClass:tempClass]) {
                [mutableControllers removeObject:tempController];
                continue;
            }
        }
        tempClass = va_arg(controllerList, Class);
    }

    va_end(controllerList);
    return [mutableControllers copy];
}
```